# copy all <ext> files to a tar.gz file

Tags: unix, grep, tar

In Unix how can create a compressed archive (tar.gz) including all files, with a given extension, in a directory tree (including all its sub-directories) ?

Something like this :

```
ls -lR | grep <ext> | tar xxxx file.tar.gz
```

Comment: why did I get a downvote? I have researched it and it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You meant:

```
find -name '*.ext' -exec tar -rzf file.tar.gz {} +
```

?

1. `-name '*.ext'` finds all files with `.ext` suffix,
2. `-exec ... {} +` means execute the command with all found files passed as arguments,
3. `tar -rzf file.tar.gz` means *append* files to `file.tar.gz`. It's 'append' in case the argument list gets too long, and the `tar` invocation needs to split. `-r` is for append, `-z` is for gzip-compress, `-f` is used to specify archive filename.

Note that if `file.tar.gz` exists already, you need to `rm` it first.

Comment: mmm I get an error -bash-3.00$ find -name '*.sas'
find: illegal option -- n
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list

Comment: What kind of system is this? You can try appending `.` after `find`; i.e. `find . -name '*.ext'`.

Comment: it works now, but it doesn't look compressed to me, I did use -rcf

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the `.gz` part. `gzip -9 file.tar` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

```
find your_path -type f -name "*.your_ext" | xargs tar -czf your_file.tar.gz
```

Comment: Do you have a reason to misuse `xargs`?

Comment: Why do you think it's a misuse ?

Comment: Because it's a misuse. You're using two tools to accompany what `find` is able to do itself. `man find`, grep for `xargs`.

Comment: :) It's a misuse :) No, it's à use, depending on your school you may want to use `find` alone, its your right and I respect it, in my school we use them both. So please `man respect` ;)

Comment: I can't respect that school because that school catches random people of the street and teaches them to write incorrect invocations. The `xargs` variant won't handle all filenames correctly (think of newline), the `-exec` one does.

Comment: Then think of `find -print0` and `xargs -0`. Find is a confusing command which includes a little-language with weird substitution rules (`{}`?!). In contrast I can look at (or write) the version with `xargs` and understand it promptly. People use different tools in different ways, and just because it's not the way _you_ use them, doesn't mean it's misuse.